# Оптимизация приложения при настройке android компонентов фрагмента в ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Столкнулся с проблемой производительности при применении настроек к множеству компонентов за раз. К примеру будет код ниже:

```
textView.text = "hello world"
recyclerView.adapter = SomeRecyclerAdapter()
recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
editText.setText("hello world")
```

Примерно такой код у меня есть в 10 фрагментах, которые подгружаются при пролистывании viewpager'a, его код:

```
view_pager.adapter = ViewPager2Adapter() // Пользовательский адаптер для ViewPager2, в нём 10 фрагментов
view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = 4
view_pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageScrolled(
       position: Int,
       positionOffset: Float,
       positionOffsetPixels: Int
    ) {
        if(view_pager.offscreenPageLimit < position) {
            view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = position
        }   
    }
})
```

Производительность страдает как и с пользовательским OnPageChangeCallback, так и без него.
Есть какие-то пути решения такой проблемы? Может настраивать компоненты в другом потоке?

Компоненты настраиваю в методе onViewCreated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый метод метод можно попробовать инициализировать данные во фрагменте не в методе onViewCreated, а в onResume() это должно снизить нагрузку(плюс если данные должны иницилизироваться только один раз, но нужно будет поставить какой-то флаг. Чтоб не инитить каждый раз как фрагмент будет в фоне) 
Если этого будет не достаточно, то

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
    super.onPageSelected(position)
    //тут можно сказать определенному фрагменту
   // чтоб он про инициализировал свои данные
   //  например через callback или подписаться через rx
    }
})
```